# Moment.js formatting outputs as 'invalid date'

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs

I have a formatTime function using moment.js
but if the number comes in as NaN moment.js outputs as 'invalid date'

how can i fix this?

```
$scope.formatTime = function(time) {

    if (time>24){
        time-=24;
    }
    return moment({
        hour: Math.floor(time),
        minute: time - Math.floor(time) * 60
    }).format('h:mm a');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Moment's `isValid()` method, and acting different if it's not a valid date. For example this will return false:

```
moment("not a real date").isValid()
```

The documentation states that this is for version 1.7+ and the details for validation are available [in the Moment documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/).